# Closure of an abelian subgroup of a topological group is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

I have proved that if $G$ is a Hausdorff Topological Group and $H \subset G$ is a subgroup, then $\bar H$ is a subgroup, and that if $H$ is abelian, so is $\bar H$.

Is it possible to drop the Hausdorff Hypothesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Any nonabelian group is a topological group in the indiscrete topology, and in such a group the closure of, say, the trivial subgroup is the whole group and hence is not abelian.